# Where can I learn about android fragments?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to learn about android fragments so I need a website.

So far I only saw websites and videos that lack objectivity or just want *me* to copy/paste and not learn.

Can such  questions be posted in Stack Overflow, or don't they suit the Stack Overflow type of question?

Comment: Stack Exchange sites are not meant to be tutorials - the internet got enough of these.

Comment: I know that the internet is full of them. Sometimes is good to learn from a good one

Comment: True, but that's not what Stack Exchange is for. (not only Stack Overflow, all sites in the network)

Comment: I don't want a tutorial in stackoverflow, I just want to suggestions about a good website to learn.

Comment: hmm... http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ might fit. (don't take my word on it, your questions might still be downvoted and closed)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't see how it could possibly be on topic there.

Comment: @Servy "android fragments" sounds like some software. And Software Recommendation site sounds like a site that might offer help in finding good places to learn about the software. Like I said, not 100% sure it would fit, but surely no other site fits better.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't see anything in their help center to indicate that it'd be on topic, and plenty of the same verbiage seen on SO (with respect to opinions) to indicate that it wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: You know that the number one website on the internet is designed to aggregate everything that's available online and make it discoverable by people like you!  You simply visit the website, enter in what you want, and you get literally hundreds of thousands of candidate links.  You can visit a few, learn more about what you're trying to do, and then *return to this aggregation service with an even better query!* You'll find better results this time!  Repeat this cycle until you've mastered your subject!  Go forth and be brilliant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can such questions be posted in Stack Overflow, or don't they suit the Stack Overflow type of question?

The very first step for a relatively new user before posting to any SE site is to see what's on-topic and off-topic. Stack Overflow has this to mention:

> #### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> [If] your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

As you can see, your question doesn't fit into the aforesaid reasons, so you shouldn't ask it there. Also, they have this info under *off-topic* reasons:

> Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

That should make things clear for now, and would possibly help you to post a question on any SE site, I assume.

Comment: The question isn't fit for [Android.se] as well. You can check out its [policies](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if unsure.

Comment: Oh, here is the [source](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which I quoted but forgot to reference.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not appropriate to post questions asking for tutorials.

Comment: Is there a place for my question?

Comment: @AntónioPaulo Not in SE.